# Regexp that matches when word is not found

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I need a regexp that returns something (the entire sentence) when the string does NOT match a keyword.

Maybe this is strange, but I need something like this in javascript:

```
"any word".match(/.*(?!my key)/) => I would want ["any word"]
"my key".match(/.*(?!my key)/) => I would want null
```

This previous does not work.

I can't do something like, which would work:

```
if "any word".match(/my key/)
  return null
else
  return "any word"
```

because I am inside a place that receives a Regexp and executes a function if it matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, `.*` first matches the entire string, then the lookahead assertion `(?!my key)` succeeds, too (because you can't match `my key` at the end of the string, of course).

You want

```
"test string".match(/^(?!.*my key).*/)
```

Also, you might need to use the `s` modifier if your test string possibly contains newlines,  and you might want to use word boundaries (`\b`) to avoid false positives with strings like `army keypad`:

```
"test string".match(/^(?!.*\bmy key\b).*/s)
```

Comment: "my key".match(/(?!.*my key).*/) gives ["y key"], and I believe things like ".*", ".+" should not be used in (?!) (?=)

Comment: @prM: Right, I forgot the anchor! Thanks! `.*` etc. can be used in lookaheads just fine (of course it depends on what you want to achieve, and you need to look out for performance issues if you do use them, but when anchored, this is perfectly OK).

Comment: Whether or not the ".*" in (?!.*my key) is required will depend on what the programmer wants to achieve. The rest is good.

Comment: @prM: I'm assuming that he wants to check whether the test string only contains `my key` (as opposed to whether the test string consists only of `my key`) because of his second example (`if "any word".match(/my key/)`) which would match `"This is my key."`.